# configuring 3750x to handle 2nd ISP, for a separate customer/not load balancing

Tags: cisco, routing

Let me start by saying that I am not looking to load balance between 2 ISPs.

I have a site where we get an MPLS ethernet handoff from our ISP. For some reason, our marketing dept. gave a contract company the green light to have their own service dropped in to support a contractor for the next 2 years. I'm still fighting to get my supervisor to shut this down and just let the contractor run on our network as we currently do, but I need to have a solution in hand in case I can't win this battle.

What I am thinking of doing is running their internet connection into my switch stack in order to get from MPOE to contractor cubicles. (company will not pay for cabling) I obviously need a separate IP scope for this VLAN. My thoughts on this are that I should be able to make it work with a unique IP scope, a static route and maybe a couple of ACLs.

Short version:new network on my equipment, separate ISP/gateway, unique IP scope, new vlan, no intervlan routing.

Comment: @Robert-currently running ipbase. That would be a great solution, thank you.

Comment: well, when faced with upgrading IOS or pulling an extended DMARC and utilizing dedicated hardware as a 'best solution', they have opted to go with pulling cable and hardware. thank you very much for the insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put their L3 interfaces in a separate VRF you would not need ACLs. No need to even mix the routing tables.

However you would need to be running IP Services IOS.

Comment: VRF is the way to go, I second that.